# Alert block over figure in Lyx

Tags: lyx, overlays

I want to add an alert/example block over a figure in Lyx. 
Currently in the frame I use a float environment to add a figure--> then provide a pause --> add a minibox with 25% column width --> add an alert block within the minibox. Below are the snapshots of the Lyx code and the output
[image: Lyx environment]

[image: Output]

I understand the problem here. The figure somehow needs to be in the background and the alert block superimposed on it!. I dont know how to do it or is it even possible to do so in Lyx.

Any suggestions?

Thanks